# Flutter Keyboard makes widgets hide

Tags: flutter

I have the problem that when I open the keyboard it hides the widgets behind it (screen is not resizing).
I saw some solutions in differents threads but none worked with me!
tried the following:

- using the option of resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true inside the scafold.
- using singlechildscroll view.
- using EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom).

The detailed code is below, please note that class Background() is to do some shading on the background, will also put its code in different code box.

main code:

```
      Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  key: _scaffoldkey,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  body: Container(
    padding:
        EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Background(),
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 200.h, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                "HELPER",
                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 91, 165),
                  fontSize: 30.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                softWrap: false,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: loading
                      ? const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        )
                      : currentstate ==
                              MobVerificationState.SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE
                          ? getMobileFormWidget(context)
                          : getOtpFormWidget(context)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

the problem is with getMobileFormWidget(context) and getOtpFormWidget(context))
they are different states, each is column which contains some widgets inside.

the background class code:

```
       return ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (bounds) => const LinearGradient(
    colors: [
      Color.fromARGB(255, 248, 247, 247),
      Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 91, 165),
    ],
    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  ).createShader(bounds),
   child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`, and the screen will be automatically elevated to the keyboard border, example:

```
Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Container(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              ShaderMask(
        shaderCallback: (bounds) => const LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color.fromARGB(255, 248, 247, 247),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 91, 165),
          ],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        ).createShader(bounds),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 200, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                "HELPER",
                
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                softWrap: false,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: 
                      ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (build, index){
                        return TextField();
                      }))
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I used a random `listView` to clarify, instead of the `getMobileFormWidget` and `getOtpFormWidget` that you didn't provide with your code.

Comment: hi Abdallah, thanks but I used this too, no affect at all, also tried to make the top level widget is the stack, containing the background and scalffold (where everything is inside it), also no affect.

Comment: @SherifSaidElahl did you try the code i posted? keyboard is pushing the page up as you want.

Comment: I tried it too with the same problem in my side. btw I was using the same code "exactly" on the same device, but in a different project, and it was working totally fine. took it copy paste and it is not working!

Comment: This might me an emulator issue, try a physical device to see if it persists

Comment: i am on real device, running both applications together, with the same exact code, one is wokring and one isn't! .. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

after two days of trials nothing worked except the code below, I adapted it to my code.

```
 import 'dart:ui';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class KeyboardPaddingTest extends StatefulWidget {
 const KeyboardPaddingTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _KeyboardPaddingTestState createState() => _KeyboardPaddingTestState();
  }

 class _KeyboardPaddingTestState extends State<KeyboardPaddingTest> {
 EdgeInsets _viewInsets = EdgeInsets.zero;
 SingletonFlutterWindow? window;
 final _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 window = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window;
 window?.onMetricsChanged = () {
  setState(() {
    final window = this.window;
    if (window != null) {
      _viewInsets = EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(
        window.viewInsets,
        window.devicePixelRatio,
      ).add(EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(
        window.padding,
        window.devicePixelRatio,
      )) as EdgeInsets;
    }
    });
    };
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: double.infinity,
  color: Colors.greenAccent[100],
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _viewInsets.bottom),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 200.0,
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[100],
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textFieldController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Tap to show keyboard',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Text(
          'Testing Keyboard',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      ),
      ),
      );
      }
      }
```